# Django models using same IDs for Primary Key which were created via bulk upload

Tags: python, django, postgresql, key

I have created several models and filled them via a csv bulk upload. Now I wanted to use `request.GET.get("item")` and work with the resulting ID of the item.

But I realized (checked in the postgres tables) that the models are using the same ID's which are set to be primary keys and which were set automatically by django.

So now if `request.GET.get("item")` returns an ID of 2 for example, this ID refers to multiple model instances and is not a unique identifier for a specific object.

My question is:

How can I make my objects, now that they are uploaded, unique and query them accordingly by ID? / Changing the current ID to being a unique ID ?

**EDIT**:

Postgres Table 1:

id                                           | integer                | not null default nextval('appname_tablename_id_seq'::regclass)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "otherapp_cartitem" CONSTRAINT "otherapp_cartitem_gas_item_id_fda21436_fk_appname_tablename_id" FOREIGN KEY (gas_item_id) REFERENCES appname_tablename(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

id |         Column 1           |
----+-----------------------------

1 | manufacturer a

2 | typ b

Postgres table 2:

id                 | integer                | not null default nextval('appname_tablename2_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "appname_tablename2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Referenced by:
    TABLE "otherapp_cartitem" CONSTRAINT "a8ac384c4b19c16387e7656d0c2b5542" FOREIGN KEY (direct_item_id) REFERENCES appname_tablename2(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

id |         Column 1           |
----+-----------------------------

1 | manufacturer c

2 | typ d

3 | name a

The corresponding models don't have anything special on them as far as I see it (simplified version below):

```
class tablename(models.Model):
      manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, )
      typ = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, )

class tablename2(models.Model):
      manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, )
      typ = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, )
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, )
```

I didn't create the ID column. This was generated by django and I supposed django would create a PK for every item automatically. Am I mistaking and the ID column doesn't represent the primary keys?

Comment: What you describe is not possible. A primary key is unique by definition. Please show your models - have you overridden the definition of the id field?

Comment: Updated! What you say is exactly my question. I thought it wouldn't be possible. So I'm probably wrong in my understanding of the generation of primary keys or the generated ID column in my tables..maybe you can help me out on this one?